# How can I use Bibulous with latexmk from the command line?

Tags: bibtex, latexmk, bibulous

I would like to use [Bibulous](http://nzhagen.github.io/bibulous/) in place of BibTeX in order to create a custom bibliography format more easily. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to invoke Bibulous from the command line. (I can invoke Bibulous manually as `python bibulous.py <file>.aux`, but not as part of my normal build process with `latexmk`.)

In its [Getting Started](http://nzhagen.github.io/bibulous/getting_started.html) section, Bibulous says this:

> For general users, all that is needed is place the main bibulous.py file into the Python path and to tell LaTeX to use Bibulous rather than BibTeX as their bibliography engine.

I'm probably being clueless, but I don't see *how* to "tell LaTeX to use Bibulous rather than BibTeX" as my bibliography engine.

Normally I build files using `latexmk` and a Makefile, and I'm unsure what to add to the Makefile or to `.latexmkrc` in order to swap Bibulous for BibTeX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`latexmk` has a `$bibtex` variable, so you can perhaps set something like

```
$bibtex = 'python bibulous.py %B.aux';
```

in the `.latexmkrc` file. `%B` is the filename without extension.

To clarify one point: depending on how you install Bibulous, you may need to enter a fuller path to `bibulous.py`. Even so, it's relatively simple:

```
$bibtex = 'python /full/path/to/bibulous.py %B.aux';
```